# Using the Text Function in Excel

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, format, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a new column (Column G) showing the month job applications were sent in from the dataset shown in the image below using the Text function in excel

[image]

However, I noticed that once the date format changed  in Column B (row 13131), I was no longer able to generate application month, but was instead given a repeat of what is in Column B. Is there an efficient way of resolving this without having to manually reformat Column B one by one. I have tried formatting the column as a whole but that didn't work.

Comment: What value is the date supposed to be in row 13131?  It looks like 13th January 2019 but that's not close the the dates in rows above.

Comment: The date is indeed 13th January 2019. Yes you're right. It's not close to the dates above. however, I don't believe that should be an issue no?

Comment: The cause of your problem seems to be that the value in `B13131` is not a "real date". Rather it is a text string that looks like a date. The values above that are "real dates". Hence your results. It would be best to work on that issue.  One way to get into this problem could be if the original data is from a CSV file with dates written in `MDY` format when your Windows Regional Settings call for `DMY` format. If that is the case, you need to IMPORT rather than OPEN the csv file, and designate the correct date format of the Source at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answer to my question, no it's not the issue, I was just checking.  You might be able to resolve the issue if you use 'Text to Columns'.  It's a great feature.  I would suggest selecting column B from row 13131 down to the bottom.  Use 'Text to Columns' on the 'Data' part of the Ribbon.  When you get to step 3, choose 'Date' under 'Column data format' and then 'MDY' as the format.

Hopefully this works for you, it's usually pretty good.